# BZIP2 multiple files without losing original files

Tags: bzip2

I want to bzip2 about 1000 files. However, I am tasked to not remove the old files and leave both the original and its bz2 file in the same folder. What is the quickest way to do this.

Just to rephrase my question, suppose I have file1.txt, file2.txt, file3.txt...file1000.txt, I would need its bz2 versions in the same folder without removing them.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

The `-k` option is described in the `bzip2` manual as

> `-k` `--keep`
>
> Keep (don't delete) input files during compression or decompression.

So if you compress the files with `bzip2` as ordinary, but add `-k`, you would not delete the original files.

To compress all `.txt` files in a single directory:

```
bzip2 -k ./*.txt
```

If that generates an "Argument list too long" (as it would do if you have many tens of thousands of files), use a simple shell loop instead:

```
for name in ./*.txt; do
    bzip2 -k "$name"
done
```

Comment: @kusalnanda, can I do the above by creating bzip2 files in a different directory instead of creating in the same. So basically can I give something like this bzip2 -k ./*.txt /destination

Comment: @mywayz `bzip2 -k -c "$name" >"destdir/$name.bz2"`.  The `-c` option make `bzip2` write to standard output. You then redirect this to an appropriately named file in some other location.  You can only do this on a single file at a time though, or you would concatenate all files into one.

Comment: Thanks Kusal, in you above comment, I do not see anywhere where the command will know which kind of file I want to BZIP in bzip2 -k -c "$name" >"destdir/$name.bz2". I am assuming I do not need to replace the first "$name" with anything? Also quotes signs remain as is right?

Comment: suppose I want to create bz2 of all the .txt files to a new location, so my command should look like this - bzip2 -k -c "$./*.txt" >"/mydirectory/mywayz/$name.bz2"

Comment: @mywayz I was using the command that you would need to insert into the loop I have show in my answer (in place of the `bzip2` command that is there). As I said, you can't compress all files in one go but have to loop over each.

Comment: Okay Kusal, then I have a related question. I just put  bzip2 -k -c ./*.txt > /scratch/sealu2/bzipped thinking that all the .txt files from my current folder will get saved there in the /scratch/sealu2/bzipped folder but I get the error that this is a directory. I mean that is where I want the files to be saved. Is it trying to understand that that my command has just one file?

Comment: @mywayz What that command is doing is compressing all files into one single compressed file, and it tries to write that file to the file `/scratch/sealu2/bzipped`. Since that is a directory, you get an error. For the 3rd time now: _You can't compress all file in one command_ and at the same time write them elsewhere. To be unnecessarily explicit, this is the command you need: `for name in ./*.txt; do bzip2 -k -c "$name" >"/scratch/sealu2/bzipped/$name.bz2"; done`

Comment: Thanks buddy. Appreciate all your help.  This helps

Answer (score 0):

`find /PATH/ -type f -execdir bzip2 -k '{}' \;`

In `/PATH/`, recursively find all regular **f**iles, and **exec**ute in their respective **dir**ectories `bzip2 -k /PATH/TO/FILE` which would keep the original file as well as the `bzip2` compressed file.

So, a folder structure like

```
/PATH/file1
/PATH/file2
/PATH/folder1/
/PATH/folder1/file1
/PATH/folder1/file2
```

would result in

```
/PATH/file1
/PATH/file1.bz2
/PATH/file2
/PATH/file2.bz2
/PATH/folder1/
/PATH/folder1/file1
/PATH/folder1/file1.bz2
/PATH/folder1/file2
/PATH/folder1/file2.bz2
```

Above solution would run in serial, to make things faster, let's run it in parallel

```
find /PATH/ -type f | xargs -L1 -P10 -I{} bzip2 -k '{}'
```

Recursively find regular **f**iles in `/PATH/` and pass them as input to `xargs` which then parses input in **L**ines (**1** at a time), spawn a **P**rocess (at max **10** running at a time in parallel), use **I**nput placeholder **{}** for processed input (i.e a line in this case). And execute `bzip2 -k` for that placeholder

Have quoted the placeholder in case, any of your filenames have whitespace in them.

Comment: Can you explain what this is doing before I try this. Want t make sure I don't remove any of my current file. Thanks

Comment: Hello GypsyCosmonaut, do I have to put anything in those curly brackets. And I and that last back slash remains as is?

Comment: Everything remains as is except `/PATH/` of course

Comment: Thanks will try this and report back, as I am not in front of pc

Comment: Why use sudo here?

Comment: @dhag it's not necessary, but just in case. Removed.

Comment: The `-L` and `-I` options (and `-n`) to `xargs` are mutually exclusive. You are likely only getting the effect of the last one, or `xargs` may do something implementation-specific.

Comment: From `man xargs`, `-I` implies `-x` and `-L1`, so yes there is no need for `-L1` there, but it will still work fine being explicit there. Thanks @Kusalananda